# Get index of LinkToAction on table - WD Java

Tags: java, webdynpro

I have a data table and I want to show detail when clicking each row on it. But the index always returns 0.

```
int index= wdContext.getCurrentElement().index();
wdComponentAPI.getMessageManager().reportSuccess("test "+ index);
```

[image]

Please help me review and give your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here. **First optio**n:

```
wdContext.node<YourNode>.getLeadSelection().index();
```

Pay attention to get lead selection of your node but not of the root context. Also context mapping should be properly defined for this to work.

**Second option** is to use [wdDoModifyView event](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/WDJava/Methods+Present+in+the+View+and+Component+controllers):

```
wdDoModifyView(...)
{
if (firstTime)
 {
  IWDLinkToAction link = (IWDLinkToAction) view.getElement("LinkID");
  link.mappingOfOnAction().addSourceMapping("nodeElement", "rowElement");
 }
}
```

Here we map built-in parameter `nodeElement` to our target `rowElemen` parameter which would be used in *LinkToAction* handler.

```
void onActionLinkClicked(..., I<DataSourceNode>Element rowElement)
{
 /* do whatever with row element */
}
```